# My .filter in react lost when refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying create a search bar, when user want to search a product.

Here is my Search Input:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  navigate(`/search/${searchTerm}`);
  setIsShowing(false);
  setOpacity(1);
};

<FormSearch onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <SearchInput type="text" 
               placeholder="Type something to search" 
               onChange={(e)=> setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} 
               defaultValue={searchTerm} />
  <SearchButton type="submit" value="Search" />
</FormSearch>
```

and here is the router when click search and take user to another page:

```
<Router>
  <SearchInfo
    path="/search/:title "
    searchTerm={searchTerm}
  />
</Router>
```

and here is my react function for the page after search:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const SearchInfo = (props) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const getProductsAPI = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/products")
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductsAPI();
  }, [props]);
  const InfoWrapper = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <InfoWrapper>
                  {products
        .filter((product) =>
          product.title.includes(props.searchTerm.toUpperCase())
        )
        .map((filteredItem, i) => (
          <Item key={i}>
              <ItemTitle> {filteredItem.title} </ItemTitle>
          </Item>
        ))}
      </InfoWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchInfo;
```

if I refresh the page it will show all my products instead of just `props.searchTerm`.
How can I fix this? Seems like the props I passed from route didn't session

Comment: how does your url look in the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

The searchTerm comes from the state and props you pass, not from the url. Youll need to get the param from the Router and use that instead, see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Something like:

```
<Router>
  <SearchInfo path="/search/:searchterm"/>
</Router>
```

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchInfo = (props) => {
  let { searchterm } = useParams();

  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      <InfoWrapper>
        {products.filter((product) => product.title.includes(searchterm))
        .map((filteredItem, i) => (
          <Item key={i}>
              <ItemTitle> {filteredItem.title} </ItemTitle>
          </Item>
        ))}
      </InfoWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your `SearchInfo` have `path` as prop but I think `path` is supposed to be managed by router, so the ideal structure would be:

```js
<Router path="/search/:searchterm" component={SearchInfo} />
```

Then you can easily access to location info:

```js
const SearchInfo = (props) => {
  // Here is what you need
  const {
    match: { params },
  } = props;
}
```